# In Excel, is there any way to quickly advance a time cell by one minute?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

For example, let's say Cell A1 has a value of 11:37:00 PM (displayed as 23:37). I want to click the cell and immediately advance it to 11:38:00 PM (displayed as 23:38). It's annoying to have to delete and type the new time value into the area on top .

Comment: What do you mean by "immediately advance it"? If you click a cell with a time in it, you want it to immediately increment by one?  Should this work for a specific cell, or any cell?

Comment: You can use VBA to do this but it will mean the Excel sheet must be saved as an `.xlsm` file type (Excel Macro Enabled Workbook). This will give an additional security prompt for users.

Comment: Just one specific cell? you'd have to make a button pointing to a macro

Comment: Jonathan, how about some feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 2):

This will enable you to click any cell in column A and add 1 minute. Add this sub to the sheet where you want to add the minutes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then 'edit this to change a different column
        Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column) + TimeValue("00:01:00")
    End If
End Sub
```

**Extra**

In case you have dates and don't want to update the dates, use this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then 'edit this to change a different column
        var = DateValue(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value)
        Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column) + TimeValue("00:01:00")
        var2 = DateValue(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value)
        If var <> var2 Then
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value = Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value - 1
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This might have some strange effects if the addition causes it to go over midnight, it might be worth adding a check to go back 1 day if it does.

Comment: thanks for the reccomendation, hadn't thought about that, but i'll look into it if it's necessary

Comment: @bendataclear, updated my answer. Could you verify too if it works properly.